# UPDATE table using SELECT IN with multiple output column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Query error: Subquery of type IN must have only one output column.
How can I update this table? thank you

```
UPDATE table
       SET ViewItem = SessionStart
       WHERE  (event_date, user_pseudo_id) 
       IN 
       (SELECT event_date, user_pseudo_id
        FROM table
        WHERE ViewItem > SessionStart
        GROUP BY event_date, user_pseudo_id
        ORDER BY event_date, user_pseudo_id
       )
;
```

Comment: what exactly sql engine you use? you have too many tags here?

Comment: I am using Google BigQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below

```
UPDATE table
       SET ViewItem = SessionStart
       WHERE  (event_date, user_pseudo_id) 
       IN 
       (SELECT AS STRUCT event_date, user_pseudo_id
        FROM table
        WHERE ViewItem > SessionStart
        GROUP BY event_date, user_pseudo_id
        ORDER BY event_date, user_pseudo_id
       )
;
```

Comment: consider also voting up the answer :o)